# Proposed question: How can two identical virtual addresses point to different physical addresses?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been contemplating asking this question (for no reason other than satisfying my curiosity) on a Stack Exchange but don't know which one to ask it on.

> Following a fork() call in Linux, two processes (one being a child of
>   the other) will share allocated heap memory. These allocated pages are
>   marked COW (copy-on-write) and will remain shared until either process
>   modifies them. At this point, they are copied, but the virtual address
>   pointers referencing them remain the same. How can the MMU (memory
>   management unit) distinguish between the two? Consider the following:
>
> 1. Process A is started
> 2. Process A is allocated a memory page, pointed to by the virtual address 0x1234
> 3. Process A fork()s, spawning process B
> 4. Process A and B now share virtual address 0x1234, pointing to the same physical memory location
> 5. Process B modifies its 0x1234 memory page
> 6. This memory page is copied and then modified
> 7. Process A and B both have virtual address 0x1234, but this points to different physical memory addresses
>
> How can this be distinguished?

Answer (score 1):

If you've done some research/self-study and can show in the question what research you've done, this could be suitable for [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).  As always, read [the help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over there before posting.